# How to implement Airbnb menu and map side by side?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a menu and map side by side similar to Airbnb's implementation. Specifically where the map stays under the side menu as you resize the window.

I've tried making the menu and map have an absolute position each with a specific percentage width. It does place them side by side, but when I try to make the menu vertically scrollable the map starts overlapping with the side menu when you resize the window.

```html
<div style="height: 100%;">
  <div class="show-rows">
      <div class="show-row" *ngFor="let show of shows; let i=index"> 
      <div>
  <div>
  <div #map style="height: 100%; width: 74%; position: absolute; left: 500px;"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.show-rows {
  padding: 16px;
  width: 26%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I expect the map to stay under the side menu and not overlap, but when I resize the window the map starts overlapping with the side menu.

Here is a link to the Airbnb example I'm trying to implement.

[Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com/s/New-York/homes?refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&adults=0&children=0&checkin=&checkout=&click_referer=t%3ASEE_ALL%7Csid%3A6d4d51b0-c2e5-4dbf-b7b2-5526877e30c0%7Cst%3ALANDING_PAGE_MARQUEE&search_type=UNKNOWN&allow_override%5B%5D=&zoom=11&search_by_map=true&sw_lat=40.64006381787952&sw_lng=-74.19123365234373&ne_lat=40.82685417335118&ne_lng=-73.77924634765623&place_id=ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g&s_tag=PDu7NoS1)

This is what my implementation looks like with the overlapping [Menu and Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrYvc.jpg)

Comment: you must note that air bnb is using a library to stick that map so that only the menu scrolls. you will need to do much more than just applying the above css you've provided. you might wanna try semantic-ui sticky <https://semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky.html?

Comment: Let me know if you can sort it out or I'll work it out for you.

Comment: Thanks @MosiaThabo I was able to figure it out with your suggestion of using semantic-ui sticky. I didn't end up using semantic-ui but instead used angular-sticky-things https://github.com/w11k/angular-sticky-things#scroll-in-container

Comment: Well done. I love these libraries, they make life way easier. Well done again.

Comment: @MosiaThabo Ya, they truly do. I appreciate your help, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="height: 100%;">
  <div class="show-rows">
      <div class="show-row" *ngFor="let show of shows; let i=index"> 
      <div>
  <div>
  <div #spacer></div>
  <div stickyThing [spacer]="spacer">
      <div #map style="width: 65%; position: absolute; left: 500px;" [ngStyle]="{'height': getViewPortHeight()}"></div>
  </div>
</div>

.show-rows {
  padding: 16px;
  width: 26%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I was able to solve this by using angular sticky things.
Here is a link on how to install and use [angular-sticky-things](https://github.com/w11k/angular-sticky-things#scroll-in-container).

Comment: Well Done Manuel.